# Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object when the object exists?

Tags: php

Trying to get the difference between two DateTime objects.  With the below code, I can echo out the `$endSub` variable and get a string like `2012-5-26T00:00:00-04:00` which is exactly what I need.  However, I get the error in the title if I do not `exit()` the code on the `$interval =` line.  Can anyone see a reason this would occur?

```
if ($todays_month >= 6){
    $endSub = new DateTime(($startYear+1).'-5-'.$startDay);
}else{
    $endSub = new DateTime($startYear.'-5-'.$startDay);
}

echo $endSub->format(DATE_RFC3339);
exit();

$interval = $startSub->diff($endSub);
```

Comment: `$startSub` is not `$endSub`. I don't see `$startSub` assigned anywhere in your code …

Comment: maybe give us declaration/operations you are doing on `startSub`, so we can help you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  As soon as I posted this and reviewed the code posted, I realized I left that out, then looked at my actual code and seen that `$startSub` was not cast as a `DateTime` object, which was my issue.  But I couldn't remove my post by that point.  Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where did the `startSub` variable come from? its surely a primitive or null.

Comment: Actually, this was the issue.  As soon as I posted it, I realized it was of type `date` and not `DateTime`.  But by the time I verified this, there were already answers.  Thanks for the quick response.  I will mark this as the answer once the mandatory time has passed.